# What is wrong with this script?

Tags: jscript

```
var isEven = function(number) {

    if (number%2 === 0) {
       return true;
    };
    else if (isNaN(number) === true) {
        return ("please input a number");
    };
    else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: You got your answer, but please try to be more precise the next time you post a question. First of all, you know it does not work, but you see a symptom: an error message. And you probably have a guess on why it deos not work too. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) more details on how to ask good questions, then improving your chances to get good answers. Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error message? Does it just not behave the way you expect or return the expected value?

Answer (score 1):

Your script should not have the ; behind your closing brackets
Try this:

```
var isEven = function(number){

    if (number%2 === 0) {  
       return true;  
    } else if (isNaN(number)===true) {  
       return  ("please input a number");  
    } else { 
       return false;  
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1, though the last semicolon is valid (but not required) because this is a statement assigning a function to a variable, not a function declaration.